# Can you work with Vim on iPad Mini with an external keyboard?

Tags: terminal, ssh, vi

I'm considering to buy an iPad Mini and use it -- among other things -- for programming using Vim. I would connect via SSH to a Digital Ocean server and start Vim there. I would use an external (physical) keyboard when working with Vim.

Which app should I use on the iPad to get the best VIM experience over SSH and which issues (e.g. due to keyboard layout) I have to expect?

PS: Note that I don't intend to use the iOS port of Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Prompt 2](https://panic.com/prompt/) to connect over SSH to my server. It's a paid app, but I never had an issue with it, it's really reliable. If your connection is good enough you won't appreciate any lag. Vim works great with it.

Can't tell you about external keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought Ipad Mini 5th for same purporses, I'm still not sure about about this idea at all, but ssh/mosh works really well using "Blink" app, git can be used directly throught "Working Copy" app, vim works smoothly throught mosh, also there is theme supporting, and different fonts for terminal, also I found app "Dash" usefull for documentations, and "HTTPBot", for debugging REST (or any others) APIs. Hope it'll helps someone who want to try this idea.

P.S I'm not sure about size of screen and development workflow using just one port (if it's lightning, not a usb-c)...so you have to think twice before implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have used [Reflection](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reflection-for-unix-ssh-client/id920472514?mt=8) for years. It's a breeze to work with, and feels lightweight while using it, but there is much power behind the app (plus, it's free) 
Another option is [Serverauditor](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/serverauditor-ssh-shell-console/id549039908?mt=8), I frown upon it because of in-app purchases, but it is a solid app.

Comment: Are you using `vi`/`vim` on the remote system? If yes, what are your experiences with that setup?

Comment: Did you experience any lag, i. e. you press a key and the symbol appears 1 second later on the screen?

Comment: No lag when connection is good. @patrix am using vim on system. Experiences are great, works with my bluetooth keyboard. Never used vim app on iOS. Always ssh into machine, very little lag on login, and after login there is none.